# Не могу выполнить UPDATE и INSERT внутри триггера, получаю две ошибки

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER `set_book_instance_available_on_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `issue_cards`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE `book_instances`
    SET `is_available` = TRUE
    WHERE `id` = OLD.`id_book_instance`;
    INSERT INTO `issue_cards_history` (`id_reader`, `id_book_instance`, `time`, `period`, `return_time`)
    VALUES (OLD.`id_reader`, OLD.`id_book_instance`, OLD.`time`, OLD.`period`, OLD.`return_time`);
END;
```

[image: Вот скрин]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выполнять один запрос внутри триггера, то все впорядке, но когда два,то получаю ошибки.

Comment: А где DELIMITER? Самое главное - это сообщение об ошибке никак не относится к MySQL, оно сгенерировано программой-клиентом, и все вопросы именно к ней.

Answer (score 0):

в триггерах нельзя использовать `UPDATE INSERT DELETE`

Comment: объясните, что вы имеете в виду, в одном триггере вполне могут вызываться несколько действий.